# Jolt Transform JSON Spec map with dynamic values

Tags: json, jolt

I need to transform below Input JSON to output JSON and not sure about how to write spec for that output.
compare filed values in JOLT transformation

Here is the input:

```json
{
  "body": {
    "productConfigurations": [
      {
        "productConfiguration": {
          "selected": true,
          "productSpecification": {
            "id": "1776911"
          },
          "productOffering": {
            "id": "1777341"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "productConfiguration": {
          "selected": true,
          "productSpecification": {
            "id": "247541"
          },
          "productOffering": {
            "id": "735501"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "productConfiguration": {
          "productSpecification": {
            "id": "280801"
          },
          "productOffering": {
            "id": "735501"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

expected output:
I need to transform below Input JSON to output JSON and not sure about how to write spec for that output. compare filed values in JOLT transformation.

```json
{
  "body": [
    {
      "id": "1777341",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "1776911"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "735501",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "247541"
        },
        {
          "id": "280801"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following successive shift transformations

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "productSpecification": {
                "id": "@(2,productOffering.&).products[].&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.id",
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "body[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where the main idea is to determine the common `id` values of the `productOffering` attributes through use of `"id": "@(2,productOffering.&).products[].&"` nested within `"productSpecification"` tagged object.

[image]

Comment: This is failing when we have only one productConfiguration.

Comment: Yes, you're right @Sandy . The redundant step(the former third one) is removed. Btw, have you ever checked out the answer provided for your second question?